# Capture payment online after create quote programmatically

Tags: magento2, module, admin-controller, admin-order-create, paypal-payflow-pro

I need programmatically to capture payment online using the PayPal Payflowpro method and credit card details. Also, create an order number and invoice after creating a quote then setting quote_id in the backend session. any suggestion on how it can be done

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution to process orders programaticlly and capture payment online using the PayPal Payflowpro method

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/199639)